# npm run build is returning an error when I try to deploy a react app on firebase

Tags: javascript, npm

````
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\god\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\god\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Myname\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-02T07_53_41_547Z-debug.log```
````

Comment: it says `package.json` file doesn't exist in that directory. looks lie you are running `npm` in the wrong directory

Answer (score 1):

You should check you have a package.json file in the directory you run `npm install` because the error isn't linked with npm.